# Images and Angles

Tags: geometry

Let $\Delta ABC$ be an isosceles triangle where $\angle ACB = 120^\circ$ . Let $P$ be the point on the side $AB$ such that $\angle ACP = 70^\circ$. Let $S$ be the reflection in line $CP$ and let $A'=S(A)$ and $B'=S(B)$.

Compute the $\angle ABB'$.

I drew a diagram of the triangle, where the line $CP$ cuts the $120^\circ$ angle into $70^\circ$ and $50^\circ$, then noticed that the line $BB'$ would have to create a line that was perpendicular to the line $CP$.  I could then use the fact that the $\Delta PBC$ has angles of $50^\circ$, $100^\circ$ , and $30^\circ$ ($30^\circ$ from the fact that the big original triangle was an isosceles), and the $\Delta QBC$ - where $Q$ is the point of intersection between the line $CP$ extended and the line $B'B$ - has angles of $50^\circ$, $90^\circ$, and $40^\circ$(by the triangle rule).

Then, $40^\circ-30^\circ=10^\circ$, and so the $\angle ABB'$ is $10^\circ$.

[image]

I realize how convoluted that was, but could someone do their own calculations and verify my answer?

Comment: Please improve your question by using $\LaTeX$ and maybe adding a figure. Elementary geometry without figures is so painful!

Comment: The answer is correct but the question provides more than sufficient info. Did A', the reflection of A, come into the play?